# Magento 2 - Where to find the code for vendor/magento/framework on github?

Tags: magento2, github

I try to check the framework code of magento 2.4.5 but I can't find it on github.

Where do I find the class "Magento\Framework\Db\Select" for example on github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this in the `lib/internal` dir in github. Link below:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Select.php